# List view filter out last row data using property in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, filter

I have a list which has an itemname, index and count. Now there are more than one items with the same index, but I want to filter them out to a new List, which will only have the last row of data per index.

For example if my List is as below :

```
ALPHa  index 0 and count is 2
ALPHa  index 0 and count is 3
ALPHa  index 0 and count is 4
ALPHa  index 0 and count is 5
ALPHa  index 0 and count is 4
ALPHa  index 0 and count is 3
ALPHa  index 0 and count is 2
ALPHa  index 0 and count is 1
ALPHa  index 0 and count is 5
ALPHa  index 0 and count is 0
BETA  index 1 and count is 1
BETA  index 1 and count is 2
BETA  index 1 and count is 3
BETA  index 1 and count is 4
BETA  index 1 and count is 3
BETA  index 1 and count is 2
BETA  index 1 and count is 3
BETA  index 1 and count is 4
DELTA  index 2 and count is 4
DELTA  index 2 and count is 1
DELTA  index 2 and count is 2
DELTA  index 2 and count is 3
```

The filtered list should be like

```
ALPHa  index 0 and count is 0
BETA  index 1 and count is 4
DELTA  index 2 and count is 3
```

Could some one tell me how I can filter this out?

My code is like below :

Modal class :

```
class CartItems {
  String itemname;
  int numberofitems;
  int index;

  CartItems({
    this.itemname,
    this.numberofitems,
    this.index
  });
}
```

List

```
List <CartItems> cartItems = List();
for(int i =0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
   cartItems.add(CartItems(itemname: itemList[i].itemname, numberofitems: itemList[i].numberofitems,index:index));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **code**. 
Pass your ***raw list*** as an argument to the method which will return ***filtered*** **CartItems** **List**.

```
List<CartItems> filterList(List<CartItems> itemList){
    int currentItemsIndex = 0;
    CartItems cartItem;
    List < CartItems > cartItems = List();
    for(int i =0 ;i< itemList.length; i++) {
      cartItem = CartItems(itemname: itemList[i].itemname, numberofitems: itemList[i].numberofitems,index:itemList[i].index);
      if(currentItemsIndex == itemList[i].index){
        if(i == itemList.length-1){
          cartItems.add(cartItem);
        }
      }else{
        cartItems.add(cartItem);
      }
      currentItemsIndex = itemList[i].index;

    }
    return cartItems;
  }
```

Comment: Well, this basically returned the same List which is passed as input. But your function gave me a start and I modified the code to get the desired result.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < itemList.length - 1; i++) {

      cartItem = CartItems(itemname: itemList[i].itemname, numberofitems: itemList[i].numberofitems, index: itemList[i].index, price: itemList[i].price);
      if (itemList[i].index != itemList[i + 1].index) {

        cartItems.add(cartItem);
      }
      if (i == itemList.length - 2) {

        cartItems.add(CartItems(itemname: itemList[i + 1].itemname, numberofitems: itemList[i + 1].numberofitems, index: itemList[i + 1].index, price: itemList[i].price));
      }
    }
    return cartItems;
  }

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to get the filtered list with only the last one in each itemName.

```
List<CartItems> itemList = ...;
var filteredCartItems = new LinkedHashMap<String, CartItems>();
for (CartItems item in itemList ) {
  filteredCartItems[item.itemName] = item;
}
```

Comment: This too worked, only thing I had to filter using index , so changed the filteredCartItems to new LinkedHashMap<int, CartItems>();